# python for loop beside while loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was writing and testing something, I needed to repeat doing the "for" loop if the result wasn't successful,
-I have to use the "for loop" to pass all my list items to the function.

so I asked my self if we can use the "for" kind of loops and the "while" one in the same line like to say:

```
arNumOne=[4,5,6]
arNumTwo=[8,2,5]
vSalt = 15
for vNumOne in arNumOne:
    for vNumTwo in arNumTwo and while (vNumOne+vSalt)<20:
        do something
```

I know I can solve it by "nasting" or looping inside, anyway.. is that possible or it is just one of my crazy mind outputs?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: As your `while` condition does not depend on the values from inner `for` loop, you can just make it a simple `if` and put it inside the first `for` loop like - `if (vNumOne + vSalt) >= 20: continue`

Comment: great, thank you kuro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
arNumOne=[4,5,6]
arNumTwo=[8,2,5]
vSalt = 15
for vNumOne in arNumOne:
    for vNumTwo in arNumTwo:
        if vNumOne + vSalt < 20:
            do something
```

Comment: Or put the `if` like `if vNumOne + vSalt >= 20: continue` before the inner `for` loop. It will prevent unnecessary iteration